# Does Django really have MySQL backend already installed?

Tags: django, settings, mysql-python

I need to use the mysql backend in Django. Documentation in the settings file says just use 'django.db.backends.mysql', and this is also documented at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#engine

When I set a database setting engine to 'django.db.backends.mysql' Django errors out.

I've found references on the web that one needs to install MySQLdb. However, I look in my site-packages where I find django/db/backends/sqlite3 and django/db/backends/mysql.

So, it looks like I have the Django back ends in place. Do I have the MySQL back end installed but have a configuration problem, or do I need to install the MySQLdb package to allow the backend to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`django.db.backends.mysql` is a wrapper around MySQLdb; you will need to have MySQLdb installed for it to work, or it will raise an ImproperlyConfigured exception on startup.

The Django database backends generally work like this -- they rely on a lower-level database interface library, but they provide a uniform interface to the ORM layer.

The only backend that will work "out-of-the-box" is SQLite, but that backend is no different, it's just that the SQLite interface is built into the python distribution, so it's almost guaranteed to be present.

Comment: Thanks, @IanClelland, for the clear response. I've been spoiled with Django "Just Working". I took back end to mean the whole connection system.  I did put a suggestion into the Django documentation group to be explicit about needing this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to install MySQLdb in order to use MySQL as db backend.

Comment: gets the concise answer award

Comment: Move on, there is nothing to see here, and that are not the droids you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/install/#database-installation), it states,

> If you plan to use Django's database API functionality, you'll need to
>   make sure a database server is running.

So yes, you need to install a MySQL server in order for the backend to work.

Comment: I have a MySQL server running. The issue is whether Django allows just specifying django.db.backends.mysql is the ENGINE statement, or if in addition to that you need to install the MySQLdb package.